# How to formulate the requirements that a counterexample must satisfy?

Tags: logic

Let $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ be three statements.

Suppose now we know that if $p_1$ is true, then $p_2$ and $p_3$ are equivalent. That is, if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are true, then $p_3$ is true, and if $p_1$ and $p_3$ are true, then $p_2$ is true.

Now I want to know if the reverse is true. That is, if $p_2$ and $p_3$ are equivalent, must $p_1$ be true?

One way to disprove this is to find a counter example. How shall I formulate the requirements that a counterexample must satisfy? I have trouble understanding how to satisfy the requirement that $p_2$ and $p_3$ imply each other, although I know it means either both $p_2$ and $p_3$ are true, or neither is true. Is an example where $p_1$ is false, $p_2$ and $p_3$ are true a counterexample?

Note that $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$, more accurately $p_1(x), p_2(x)$ and $p_3(x)$ ,  are given statements about some changeable object $x$, and can't be changed except the object $x$ they are talking about. For example, in [Does $X ⊥ Y \leftrightarrow X ⊥ Y | Z$ implies $(X,Y) ⊥ Z$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416468/does-x-%E2%8A%A5-y-rightleftarrow-x-%E2%8A%A5-y-z-implies-x-y-%E2%8A%A5-z), to construct an example, we have to choose the three random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, but can't change the three statements about them.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace "$p_2\leftrightarrow p_3$" by just $q$.  You are now asking if $p\to q$ implies $q\to p$.

Comment: what is to look for when searching for a counterexample?

Comment: @Tim: HINT: Remember that $p\to q$ is always true if $p$ is false.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks. Is this a counterexample: $p_2$ and $p_3$ both are true, but $p_1$ isn't? How shall we find a counterexample that satisfies the requirement that $p_2$ and $p_3$ imply each other, although I know it means either both $p_2$ and $p_3$ are true, or neither is true.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, that would be a counterexample. A very simple way is to take $p_2$ and $p_3$ to be the same statement.

Comment: @Brian: what do you mean by " take p2 and p3 to be the same statement"? p1, p2 and p3 are supposed to be given statements which can't be changed.

Comment: @Tim: You’re constructing a counterexample, so you get to choose $p_1,p_2$, and $p_3$. To construct the counterexample, let $p_1$ be any false statement, and let $p_2$ and $p_3$ be the same true statement. Then $p_2$ and $p_3$ are certainly equivalent, and neither implies $p_1$.

Comment: @Brian: I should have added that $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ are given statements, which can't be changed. For an example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416468/does-x-%E2%8A%A5-y-rightleftarrow-x-%E2%8A%A5-y-z-implies-x-y-%E2%8A%A5-z

Comment: @Tim: If they’re given statements, then your question makes no sense: either $p_1$ is true, or it’s not true, and whether this has anything to do with the truth of $p_2$ and $p_3$ depends entirely on the specific statements involved.

Comment: @Brian. In the linked post, to construct an example, we have to choose what the three random variables $X$ $Y$ and $Z$ are, though the three statements about the random variables are given and not changeable.

Comment: @Tim: In other words, you changed the statements. They aren’t specific statements until $X,Y$, and $Z$ are specified.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
p_1 & = \Big(\ell \in \{ a,b,c,d,e,f,g \}\Big) \\
p_2 & = \Big(\ell \in \{a,b,c,w,x,y,z\}\Big) \\
p_3 & = \Big(\ell \in \{a,b,c,t,u,v,w\}\Big)
\end{align}

It is easy to see with the above statements that if $p_1$ is true then $p_2$ and $p_3$ are either both true or both false.

Now suppose we don't know whether $p_1$ is true but we learn that $t=x$, $u=y$, and $v=z$.  Learning that suddenly makes $p_2$ and $p_3$ equivalent, but it does not mean that $p_1$ must be true.

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for a concrete example, but a general formulation of a counterexample in terms of $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$. (For a concrete example, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416468/does-x-%E2%8A%A5-y-rightleftarrow-x-%E2%8A%A5-y-z-implies-x-y-%E2%8A%A5-z)